# Requirements for the transit visa and baggage information for layover in Dubai

Tags: transit, dubai

I am flying from Chennai to Toronto via Dubai, where a 21 hours layover is available in Dubai. In order to avail a transit visa, is it necessary to book a hotel? Since it's a connecting flight, what about the baggage? Due to the 21 hours layover will we get the baggage in Dubai or will we get it at the end?

Comment: baggage is not released during transit stops, as a security pre-caution.